# Parse nginx rewrite rules to extract from and to

Tags: scala, functional-programming

If I have, say, a list of nginx-esque config rewrite statement as such:

```
val rewritesList : List[String] = List(
"rewrite (?i)^/first$ http://www.firstredirect.com redirect;",
"rewrite (?i)^/second$ http://www.seconredirect.com redirect;"
)
```

And I would like to extract `from` and `to` from that list.  I am not worried about the final structure as long as I extract the info, but for sake of demonstration:

```
val rewritesMap : Map[String, String] = Map(
"first" -> "http://www.firstredirect.com",
"second" -> "http://www.seconredirect.com"
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? And what's with the slash before `/first` and `/second`? And do you really want to ignore case-insensitivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with Scala's pattern matching:

```
val rewritesList : List[String] = List(
  "rewrite (?i)^/first$ http://www.firstredirect.com redirect;",
  "rewrite (?i)^/second$ http://www.seconredirect.com redirect;"
)

val Regex = """^rewrite \(\?i\)\^/(\w+)\$ ([^ ]+) redirect;$""".r

val rewritesMap = (for {
  Regex(from, to) <- rewritesList
} yield (from -> to)).toMap

println(rewritesMap)
```

You could also use the more explicit `findFirstMatchIn` to extract a single match:

```
val rewritesMap = (for {
  str <- rewritesList
} yield {
  val m = Regex.findFirstMatchIn(str).get
  (m.group(1), m.group(2))
}).toMap
```

Both versions print (up to indentation):

```
Map(
  first -> http://www.firstredirect.com, 
  second -> http://www.seconredirect.com
)
```

Note that the latter variant will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the input data is not of the format defined by the regex. I don't know what you want to do if the data does not match the regex: you can raise exceptions, but you can also simply skip the cases that aren't parsed correctly.

Comment: Nice, thanks.  What if we have a rewrite that looks like this:  `"rewrite (?i)^/third/sub/route$ http://www.seconredirect.com redirect;"` (As in it has multiple `/` in from section)

Comment: @NiceOneMoney Then replace the plain `\w+` by the `[\w/]+`? As I said, I'm not sure why you wanted to remove the first leading `/` in the first place.

Comment: Yea, you are absolutely right it wouldn't make sense to remove it.  One more questions, for the sake of covering one more base, what if we also had `"rewrite (?i)^/fourth/another/sub/*$ http://www.seconredirect.com redirect;"` ?  We could just have `\w/\*?` right?  Now if I was to follow your suggestion of leaving the leading `/`, what would need to change in the new regex?

Comment: @NiceOneMoney if you want multiple asterisks, it would be rather `[\w/*]+`, but it then would also match `/foo*bar/baz****/blub/*`. Maybe you should ask a separate question specifically on the regex once you've collected all the cases that you want to cover, and also decided what cases you explicitly want to exclude. Comments are not very well suited for that. (The `\` was printed this time... but that was good luck; Comment section increases the chances to turn regex into mess dramatically) (Update 2: oh, see, a backslash wasn't printed... What a mess)